# C++ Convert Large Number into Hexadecimal

Tags: c++

I got a large number of this value

```
DECIMAL: 3712299789313814843
```

I want to convert it into hexadecimal using C++

I did an online conversion and I realized the

```
hexadecimal value is     3384BCFD61CEB13B
```

I found some solution online and I try convert but it give me this:

```
string hex_value(int decimal)
{
  static const string hex_digits("0123456789ABCDEF");

  string hex;
  int scratch = decimal;

  while (scratch != 0)
  {
    hex += hex_digits[scratch % 16];
    scratch /= 16;
  }

  reverse(hex.begin(), hex.end());

  return hex;
}

input= hex_value(atoi(buffer.c_str()));



HEXA: 61CEB13B
```

I think integer is too small to send in the data.. i do use NTL, namely ZZ class but i not sure how to use it in this case..

anyone can guide me on how to convert this large number into hexadecimal..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need some sort of large number library such as BigInteger (https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/). A 32-bit integer can only hold a value as large as 4 billion or so (if it's unsigned -- only as high as 2 billion or so if it's signed).

The solution you posted in your question will work just fine if scratch is declared as BigInteger rather than int.

EDIT: Also, just FYI, be wary of checking your answer with online converters. Many online converters only use 32-bit integers, and thus will give you a wrong answer.

Comment: Technically, nothing is wrong with a 64-bit int for the number that OP specified, but OP is actually even running pretty close to the limit of 64 bits with that number. An unsigned 64-bit int can count as high as 1.8 * 10^19. The number OP is dealing with is 3.7 * 10^18. Being that overflow is within one order of magnitude, OP would do well to go bigger on the int size in case he/she has to deal with larger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In your case int decimal you are using is very small to handle such a big number. Using NTL is same as regular int, so you can directly perform operations on it. Also instead of while(scratch != 0) use while(decimal != 0) here decimal will be of type ZZ.

You can check out this link for examples.

http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-ex1.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the library [gmp](https://gmplib.org) to represent big numbers: it is very intuitive and quite simple. It is mostly for C but there are some extensions for C++ that make things easier.

After representing your big number with such a library, then you can apply the steps to convert to hex:

Suppose N is your number:

1. initialise an empty string ***res***
2. Calculate N modulo 16 (the reminder of the division)
3. Represent the value you obtained in hex into a string: ex. 10 becomes "a"
4. append the result to **res**
5. N = N/16 (integer division)
6. Repeat from the second steps until N becomes 0 -

I will give the following example:

```
    #include <gmp.h> //contains all the functions and types
    #include <gmpxx.h> //contains some classes for C++
    string toFormatFromDecimal(mpz_class t);

    int main()
    {
        mpz_class N = "3712299789313814843"; //string initialisation
        std::cout<<toFormatDecimal(N);
        return 0;
    }

    string toFormatFromDecimal(mpz_class t)//mpz_class is the C++ equivalent of mpz_t
    {
        static const char hexmap[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                       '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

        string res = "";
        mpz_t temp; //C variable to store a big number
        mpz_init_set_ui(temp, 0); //initialisation
        unsigned int pos;
         do {
             pos = mpz_mod_ui(temp, t.get_mpz_t(), 16); //calculate the reminder: t%16
             res = res+hexmap[pos] ;
             t = t/16;

        } while ((mpz_cmp_ui(t.get_mpz_t(), 0) != 0));

        return string(res.rbegin(), res.rend());
    }
```